# How many ancilla qubits to use with Multiple-Control Toffoli (mct) gate in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, universal-gates

The Multiple-Control Toffoli (mct) gate takes as input: 
 1. a register containing the control qubits, 
 2. the target qubits and 
 3. a register containing ancilla qubits.

I don't know how many ancilla qubits I need to pass in for a number of $n$ controll qubits.
I've seen examples and used mct gates with 4 control qubits and 2 ancillas so I know the number of ancillas is not $n-1$ like suggested [in this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-can-i-implement-an-n-bit-toffoli-gate)

Is there a strict dependency meaning for 10 control qubits you need 5 ancillas or does the implementation adapt to the number or ancillas that are passed in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the number of ancillas is minimum $n-2$.

I found this line in the Qiskit source code of mct:

```
if len(ancillary_qubits) < len(control_qubits) - 2:
    raise AquaError('Insufficient number of ancillary qubits.')
```

Comment: Im new to QC so this may be a trivial question; Why use more than one ancilla? Im using the mct gate for my 6 qubit grover's algorithm circuit and the gate works just fine with just 1 ancilla... unless I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Qiskit, it seems fine even if I don't specify any ancilla qubit. For example, Minh Pham's answer (see below) doesn't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any ancillas at all. Just add in the controls as a list and a target and you should be good.

Take this as an example of 9 control bits

[image]

Comment: It forces you to put in atleast 1 ancilla when the control gate gets bigger than 5.