# What is a "cascade of gates"?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate

While I'm reading some literature about synthesizing quantum circuit, I couldn't understand what **cascades of Toffoli gates** means. How Toffoli cascade runs in quantum circuit?

Comment: Have you researched the meaning of a NAND-gate cascade, or in general a logic-gate cascade?  When you combine/cascade a number of NAND gates together, you can realize any boolean function.  The same is true of Toffoli gates.  For example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) states: "logic gates can be cascaded in the same way that Boolean functions can be composed, allowing the construction of a physical model of all of Boolean logic, and therefore, all of the algorithms and mathematics that can be described with Boolean logic. "

Answer (score 4):

I think a "cascade" of gates is just a fancy word for a sequence of gates that follow a certain pattern. A good example is offered in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2178/2879) that details implementing a multi-controlled-NOT gate using Toffoli gates. The pictures in that answer show Toffoli gates form two ladder-like patterns. I don't think the term "cascade" means anything more specific than that.