# How to implement a doubly controlled phase gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I'm trying to implement a doubly controlled phase gate using Qiskit. I'm aware of [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/make-a-doubly-controlled-gates-from-existing-operations) proposed solution, but it's not working on my Google collab notebook. For some reason, I cannot import the "get_controlled_circuit" part. How can I implement the following doubly controlled phase gate using Qiskit? This gate appears on this [paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-07-13-502/), fig. 2.

[image: Circuit showing the doubly controlled phase gate.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`control()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.control.html) method to create a controlled version for any gate. For example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import RZGate
from numpy import pi

phi = pi / 4
gate = RZGate(phi)

circ = QuantumCircuit(5)
circ.append(gate.control(2), [1, 3, 4])
circ.draw('mpl')
```

The result:
[image]